# Evaluate:$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n \frac1{k!}\left(-\frac12\right)^k$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Evaluate:$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n \frac1{k!}\left(-\frac12\right)^k$

MY TRY:We know that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n \frac1{k!}=e$ and
$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n \left(-\frac12\right)^k=\frac 23$ but how can we evaluate the above$?$Thank you.

Note:The answer is $\frac{1}{\sqrt e}$

Comment: We have $e^x=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k!}$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does $e^0 = 1$ if you define $e^x = \sum_{n = 0}^\infty x^n/n!$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/396823/how-does-e0-1-if-you-define-ex-sum-n-0-infty-xn-n)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/441836/how-do-we-know-that-sum-k-0-infty-fracxkk-ex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

$$e^x=\sum_{r=0}^\infty\dfrac{x^r}{r!}$$

Comment: Why the second hint?

Comment: @Did, For $$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n \left(-\frac12\right)^k=\frac 23$$ in the question

Comment: No, this is mentioned as a try and we know it leads nowhere. Adding it to your answer can only mislead the OP to think they need this fact to solve their question, while they do not.

Comment: @Did, I added that formula so that OP can compare that with that of $e^x$

Answer (score 1):

We have $\displaystyle e^x=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k!}$.

So $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n \frac1{k!}\left(-\frac12\right)^k=\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{\left(-\frac12\right)^k}{k!}=e^{\frac {-1}{2}}=\frac 1{\sqrt e}$